# Why is my firstNode.nodeValue returning null?

Tags: javascript, nodes

I'm trying to split the first p tag into 3 separate lines & display them in the second p tag by using javascript nodes. but I'm getting a return value of null.

Chrome is throwing me a runtime error saying that it 'Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of null'

Can someone pls help me?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style media="screen">
    .hideOriginal {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="oneLine">
    <span>Hi my name is John Doe</span>
    <span>I'm learning web development</span>
    <span>I'm 100 years old.</span>
  </p>

  <p class="lineBreak"></p>

  <input type="button" name="" id="fixLineBreak" value="Line Break">
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

  const breakLineFunction = () => {
    const spans = document.querySelector("#oneLine");
    document.querySelector("#oneLine").setAttribute("class", "hideOriginal")
    let newLine = "";
    const first = spans.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
    const second = spans.firstChild.nextElementSibling.firstChild.nodeValue;
    const last = spans.lastChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
    const brk = "<br><br>";
    newLine = `${first}${brk}${second}${brk}${last}`;
    document.querySelector(".lineBreak").innerHTML = newLine;
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.querySelector("#fixLineBreak").addEventListener("click", breakLineFunction);
  })

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: what is `last` supposed to be? it is where the error comes from

Answer (score 2):

```js
 const breakLineFunction = () => {
    const spans = document.querySelector("#oneLine");
    document.querySelector("#oneLine").setAttribute("class", "hideOriginal")
    let newLine = "";
    const first = spans.firstChild.nodeValue;
    const second = spans.firstChild.nextElementSibling.firstChild.nodeValue;
    const last = spans.lastElementChild.textContent
;
    const brk = "<br><br>";
    newLine = `${first}${brk}${second}${brk}${last}`;
    document.querySelector(".lineBreak").innerHTML = newLine;
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.querySelector("#fixLineBreak").addEventListener("click", breakLineFunction);
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style media="screen">
    .hideOriginal {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="oneLine">
    <span>Hi my name is John Doe</span>
    <span>I'm learning web development</span>
    <span>I'm 100 years old.</span>
  </p>

  <p class="lineBreak"></p>

  <input type="button" name="" id="fixLineBreak" value="Line Break">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @TheBombSquad Thanks, it's running now without syntax errors, but, for some reason, the browser assigns the first span element to the 'second' constant, the second span element isn't assigned anywhere, and the 'first' constant has a value of  "<br><br>".

Comment: @Schnitzler give some time to understand the code